# Do propositions 4.2.3 and 4.2.4 from Ireland & Rosen hold more generally?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am reading Ireland and Rosen's number theory book, and as far as I can tell, both propositions 4.2.3 and 4.2.4 both hold for all primes. The page containing these propositions is available in Google books [here](https://books.google.ca/books?id=HlHuBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&dq=ireland%20rosen&pg=PA46#v=onepage&q&f=false).

> **Proposition 4.2.3.** If $p$ is an odd prime, $p\nmid a$, and $p\nmid n$, then if $x^n\equiv a\mod p$ is solvable, so is $x^n\equiv a\mod p^e$ for all $e\geq 1$. All these congruences have the same number of solutions.

The book states 4.2.3 for odd primes, but the proof seems valid for $p=2$ as well, though you need to tweak the argument slightly for the assertion that the number of solutions is identical (in the $p=2$ there will always be 1 solution for any (odd) $n$).

> **Proposition 4.2.4.** Let $2^\ell$ be the highest power of $2$ dividing $n$. Suppose that $a$ is odd and that $x^n\equiv a\mod 2^{2\ell+1}$ is solvable. Then $x^n\equiv a\mod 2^e$ is solvable for all $e\geq 2\ell+1$ (and consequently for all $e\geq 1)$. Moreover, all these congruences have the same number of solutions.

Similarly, 4.2.4 is stated for $p=2$ only, but the proposition seems to hold for any prime $p$ if you change the requirement that $a$ be odd to $p\nmid a$. The proof is left as an exercise in the book, but after filling in the details I don't seem to need $p=2$ at all, and the result seems to hold for any $p$.

Can anyone confirm my suspicion that these hold for any $p$, or else help me see where we need the restrictions on $p$?

Comment: Proposition 4.2.3 is true when $p=2$, but for more trivial reasons: the hypotheses imply that $(a,2^e)=1$ and $(n,\phi(2^e))=1$, and so $x^n\equiv a\pmod{2^e}$ always has exactly one solution, namely $x\equiv a^k\pmod{2^e}$ where $k\equiv n^{-1}\pmod{\phi(2^e)}$.

Comment: I believe Proposition 4.2.4 is indeed true for all prime $p$.

Comment: @GregMartin Thank you for confirming what I thought. I suppose the propositions are as stated in the book because that's the form they'll be used later (presumably).